# Can not translate my wordpress website - no .pot file

Tags: wordpress, translation

I could not find a .pot file so I created one with Eazypo. There was no languages folder in the theme folder either. I created a "languages" folder and uploaded the newly created .pot file. I translated every string and uploaded the new .mo and .po files in the "languages" folder and I defined wp lang to have the value of the .mo file name. Not working.

Any ideas of what can be wrong or how to solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Did you add the required code so your theme can load your translation files?

Comment: I have not added any code. I can see the .mo files in the language dropdown in settings--> general-->site language, so I thought that was ok. What should I add and where? Thank you

Comment: Please check the answer below. If it helped, consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your theme to load your translation files, you need to use the [load_theme_textdomain()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain) function.

Add the following code to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function wp756531_my_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain( 'my-theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wp756531_my_theme_setup' );
```

---

**Important Notes:**

- Make sure to change the `'my-theme'` domain to the one your theme uses.
- Make sure your translation files are named after your locale(s) (eg. es_ES.mo, sv_SE.mo, etc)

Comment: I added the function and replaced 'my-theme' with the name of my theme. my .mo and .po files are in the right format: rap-es_ES.mo and rap-es_ES.po. Still not working.

Comment: As the second note says, Andrei, your translation files need to be named `es_ES.mo` and `es_ES.po`. Remove the _rap-_ part from the filename.

Comment: ^^^ That's assuming your files are Spanish translations, of course. Use the right locale if it's not Spanish.

Comment: Thanks, sorted. I appreciate the help!